# Why does increasing a variable by a list element give me an IndexError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, index-error

I am new to Python. I am trying to make a slot machine game and I keep getting this error:

```
totalScore += scores[score]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the code:

```
for dollars in range(money):
if money < 5:
    print("You don't have enough money to play anymore!")
    break
score = pyslot()
scores.append(score)
money -= 5

totalScore = 0
winnings = 0

for score in scores:
    totalScore += scores[score]
    if scores[score] < 20:
        winnings -= 5
    elif scores[score] < 50:
        winnings += 5
    elif scores[score] >= 50:
        winnings += 10
```

I'm not sure why Python is giving me this error. I don't know much about it but I thought that the "for score in scores" would keep this from happening.

Comment: Replace `scores[score]` with just `score` and it should work fine.  The `score` is the actual value, not an index; you don't need to do the extra step of indexing into the list to get the value (and the value is unlikely to be a valid index in the first place, which is why you get that error).

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but we can't know what the correct indentation should look like. Please [edit] your question to provide syntactically valid code. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

Comment: Thanks Samwise, now it's working. That was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

`for score in scores` loops over the elements in `scores`. If `scores` is a list containing `[50, 100, 200]` you will get `50` in `score` in the first iteration; `scores[50]` is clearly out of bounds, and hence you get an `IndexError`.

If you actually want to loop over the positions in the array, try

```py
for idx in range(len(scores)):
    totalScore += scores[idx]
```

but this is unnecessarily complex and slow here.

(There are situations where it makes a difference to your algorithm where in the sequence you are in each iteration. For example, if you wanted to compare the current `scores[idx]` to the adjacent scores in the list, that's somewhat hard to do if you loop directly over the items, but easy with `scores[idx-1]` and `scores[idx+1]` - obviously, you have to take care to avoid an `IndexError` at the first and last elements, but let's skip that complication here.)